# cannot register structure as boost geometry 3D point

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

These declarations fail to compile

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
struct c3d
{
    double x, y, z;
};
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( c3d, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, z )
```

compiler output:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -m64 -IC:\Users\James\code\raven-set 
-IC:\Users\James\code\boost\v1_70 -c C:\Users\James\code\TreeRobot\src\testtest.cpp 
-o obj\Debug\TreeRobot\src\testtest.o
C:\Users\James\code\TreeRobot\src\testtest.cpp:9:67: error: 'x' has not been declared
 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( c3d, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, z )
                                                                   ^
C:\Users\James\code\TreeRobot\src\testtest.cpp:9:70: error: 'y' has not been declared
 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( c3d, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, z )
                                                                      ^
C:\Users\James\code\TreeRobot\src\testtest.cpp:9:73: error: 'z' has not been declared
 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( c3d, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, z )
                                                                         ^
C:\Users\James\code\TreeRobot\src\testtest.cpp:9:75: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end of input
 BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D( c3d, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, z )
                                                                           ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))
4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))
```

Comment: Do you need to `#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>`? This [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/example/c01_custom_point_example.cpp) does.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson sez "c3d::x is not a type"

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that does it

Comment: Oh. Aha. I'm late to the party.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm will you add an answer?  Then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>`. See [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/example/c01_custom_point_example.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the necessary include

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
```